# Ng-hide not working in my Angular/Firebase app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, ng-show, ng-hide

http://stevendavisphoto.com/mc/

All code is located there. I am trying to hide the TR that says "No groups to display" when there are groups.

```
<tr ng-hide="groups.length">
     <td colspan="7">No groups to display</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You have an object not an array there you'll need to write  a function in your scope that evaluates the object appropriately to determine if there are any elements in it.  An object doesn't have a length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<tr ng-hide="groups.length === 0">
     <td colspan="7">No groups to display</td>
</tr>
```

> ng-hide and ng-show is a Boolean properties

So you must add a `expression` on the [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)  or [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

```
ng-hide="groups.length === 0"
```

### Edit

> Other members, Please take a look the below comments for OP Solution

Comment: updated on the server. doesn't seem to work. i tried this as well before you posted.

Comment: See the @ shaunhusain comment on your question. the `groups` object should be a array. Can you post your working angular code?

Comment: You need to declare `$scope.groups=[]` on globally. bcs now your `$scope.groups` not array . it's just a element object. SO please declare it globally

Comment: inside the controller?

Comment: @StevenDavisPhoto , Yes... and also you need to use this `ng-hide="groups.length === 0"` code

Comment: well right now $scope.groups = $firebase(groupsRef); so wouldnt that overwrite that?

Comment: Yes, but it's not good  to use firebase. So you need to use another property, like `IsEmpty` If the   `$scope.groups` is null then assign true value to the ISEmpty property. Does make sense?

Comment: not good to use firebase at all? or just the angularfire plugin?

i'm kinda lost.

Comment: SImple check `$scope.groups.length` in your js side. what you get? i think this threw undefined error. Please checkout that.

Comment: yeah, no length because it's not an array. i think i can use object.keys() though... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Nope . You can  solve that from here : https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html

Comment: That link explain to check if the `group` have empty value, You need to check if `$scope.Group.val()===null){$scope.IsEmpty=true;}` and then write ng-show expression look like `ng-hide="IsEmpty === 0"` . does make sense???

Comment: thank you for your patience with me. after reading that url and your code i got it working. check the code on the server now. i just used... <tr ng-show="isEmpty">

Comment: @StevenDavisPhoto , If my answer is useful, then please put mark as answer. bcs that's helps to others :(

Comment: `groupsRef.on('value', function(groups) {$scope.isEmpty = (groups.val() === null);}); ` this is looking good now :) cheers